# Simple way to use BCP to read and write from a SPROC

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, bcp

What is the simplest way to read and write files in a sproc using BCP?

Answer (score 2):

For reading a file in T-SQL, I recommend using the [`BULK INSERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) statement instead of messing with `bcp`.  They use the same underlying mechanism, but if you're in a T-SQL stored proc already, it's best not to hop out into command line land.

Unfortunately, as far as I know, there's no SQL statement you can execute to write a file.  So you'll have to resort to doing something like `exec master..xp_cmdshell @cmd`.  You can use `bcp` or `osql` as your command.  If you use `bcp`, [this page has a nice tutorial](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/creating-csv-files-using-bcp-and-stored-procedures/), but just to summarize, here's some sample code:

```
-- make a pipe delimited file... requires access to xp_cmdshell and the file system
declare @cmd varchar(8000)
select @cmd = 'bcp mydb.dbo.tblWhatever out "c:\bcp\tblWhatever.txt" -c –t| -T -S' + @@servername
exec master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
```

Comment: I tried this, the query worked, but it doesn't seem to output the file to that directory. I'll have to keep playing with this and figure out why.